# Error when combine two keras sequential models inside one functional model: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I built two keras sequential model separately, and used keras functional api to combine the two models. And between them, I applied data repacking, resizing the data passing through the two sequential model.

When I do the combination, error exists.
But I don't quite understand which object is in "NoneType".

**Another question is**, I place all zeros inside the placeholder when doing data-tensor re-packing. Will this be replaced by real data when I run model.fit, or will them be constant zero? **Is it not applicable at all to combine two sequential models with tensor resizing in between?**

```py
# I use a keras sequential model to define the 2d model "base_model_SRCNN"
# I define the 3d model still using keras sequential model as "SRnet_3d_model"

ip = Input(shape = (TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH, 1))
SRCNN_network = base_model_SRCNN(FILENAME, TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH) (ip)
#----------------------------pack frame one by one---------------------------------------
...
# In this section, I re-pack the output tensor of SRCNN_network,
# the resulted new tensor is called "package_set_tensor"
# I've checked and ensure the type of "package_set_tensor" is a tensor, and the shape is (294, 5, 352, 288, 1)
#---------------------------build 3dSRnet model--------------------------------------------
SRnet_layer = SRnet_3d_model(AMOUNT, DEPTH, TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH)(package_set_tensor)

#--------------------------test the result of combination----------------------------------
combined_model = Model(inputs = ip, outputs = SRnet_layer)

#I 've checked the type of SRnet_layer and ip are <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

**EDIT**

```py
#here's the lambda layer I defined:
def repacking(x):
    #----------------------------get shape from input tensor---------------------------------
    (AMOUNT, TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH, tmp) = x.shape
    AMOUNT = keras.backend.shape(x)[0]#will return an empty tensor
    # or using 'list(x.shape)[0]' to return a Nontype object
    DEPTH = 5
    #AMOUNT = 26
    #----------------------------pack frame one by one---------------------------------------
    FIRST = True
    HALF_RANGE = math.floor(DEPTH/2)

    for i in range(AMOUNT):
        if (i - HALF_RANGE) < 0 or (i + HALF_RANGE) >= AMOUNT:
            AMOUNT = AMOUNT - 1
        else:
            if DEPTH%2 == 0:
                RANGE = range(i - HALF_RANGE, i + HALF_RANGE)
            else:
                RANGE = range(i - HALF_RANGE, i + HALF_RANGE + 1)

            for j in RANGE:
                frame = x[j, :, :, :]  #(352, 288, 1), type = tensor
                frame = tf.reshape(frame,(1, TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH))

                if j == i - HALF_RANGE:
                    package = frame
                else:   
                    package = tf.concat([package, frame], 0)

            if FIRST == True:
                package_set = package
                FIRST = False
            else:
                package_set = tf.concat([package_set, package], 0)

    package_set = tf.reshape(package_set, (AMOUNT, DEPTH, TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH, 1))   #(294, 5, 352, 288, 1)
    return package_set
```

**But batch_size (I named as `AMOUNT`) information can not be used as for-loop index.** What should I do to use it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 71, in <module>
    model = combined(FILENAME, AMOUNT, DEPTH, TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH)
  File "/home/user1/REUS/image-reconstruction/code/functional/model_build_up.py", line 132, in combined
    combined_model = Model(inputs = ip, outputs = SRnet_layer)
  File "/home/user1/.conda/envs/tf-cpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/.conda/envs/tf-cpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 93, in __init__
    self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/.conda/envs/tf-cpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 231, in _init_graph_network
    self.inputs, self.outputs)
  File "/home/user1/.conda/envs/tf-cpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1366, in _map_graph_network
    tensor_index=tensor_index)
  File "/home/user1/.conda/envs/tf-cpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1353, in build_map
    node_index, tensor_index)
  File "/home/user1/.conda/envs/tf-cpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1325, in build_map
    node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

Answer (score 0):

Keras Layers (Models behave as a Layer) take keras layers as inputs, not tensors.

You need to pass a Layer argument to `SRnet_3d_model` not a tensor.

For instance take the simple example:

```
inp = Input(shape=(2,))
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(inp)
model = Model(inp, out)
```

The variable `inp` above is an Input Layer which does contain a placeholder tensor but also additional information that is used to build the graph. For instance, when the output layer `out` is built, keras consults the ancestor layer (which happens to be `inp` which is the argument to `Dense.call`) in order to determine the input dimensions for this layer.

Thus, while building a keras model you need to always operate in terms of layers (a model is a subclass of Layer and can be considered a complex layer).

There are circumstances where the existing layers do not provide enough functionality. Then you have two options: Lambda layers or user defined layers. Lambda layers allow you to use backend operations (or raw tf ops) inside a layer with minimum overhead. Custom layers are needed when you want the layer to own its own variables / weights.

A simple example of a Lambda layer would be a tensor slicing operations such as:

```
Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0])
```

Please note that at the tensor level you need to take the batch dimension into account. The lambda example above assumes input dimensions of (batch_size, n_features) and returns a tensor with dims (batch_size, 1).

Comment: So the problem is `SRnet_layer` is not a tensor that I can use as output? That means it's not datatype (tensor) that matters for Model construction, right?

Comment: No the problem is that ```package_set_tensor``` is a tensor and it needs to be a Layer. That is the argument to ```SRnet_3d_model.call()```

Comment: So the basic idea is I should use lambda to define a layer for data repacking in the middle, and then the output of this layer can be smoothly passed to `SRnet_3d_model`, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "data repacking" but if it is an operation like slicing / concatenation of tensors, then yes. For instance ```Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0])``` is a perfectly valid way to obtain the first feature of a result; but you need the Lambda wrapping to maintain the graph structure. Beware than inside the lambda you must account with the batch dimension. So for instance the tensor slicing example above assumes a 2-d tensor for (batch_size, n_features).

Comment: Inside lambda layer I'm trying to get the batch size to run a for-loop. When I do `AMOUNT = keras.backend.shape(x)[0]`, `AMOUNT` is like `Tensor("lambda_1/strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)`, means the batch size is empty. If I do want to do `for i in range(AMOUNT)` (which also requires me to change type from tensor to int), what should I do?

Comment: ```K.shape()``` returns a tensor; ```K.int_shape()``` returns a tuple with the shape. If you can try to vectorise operations that is preferable than a for loop.